# Parallel, Branch & Bound Traveling Salesman via MPI

Tags: c, algorithm, mpi, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to understand http://wyattgorman.com/?p=25. So far I have made not much more than `clang-format`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 20

int m_row = SIZE, m_column = SIZE, zed = 30, matrix[SIZE][SIZE], visited[SIZE], best_path[SIZE];
int best_cost = 9999999, size = SIZE;

void dfs(int city, int visited_in[], int path_in[], int path_i_in, int cost_in) {

    if (cost_in < best_cost) {

        int* visited = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);
        int* path    = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);

        int path_i = path_i_in, cost = cost_in, i;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            visited[i] = visited_in[i];
            path[i] = path_in[i];
        }

        visited[city] = 1;
        path[path_i] = city;
        path_i++;
        int leaf = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (visited[i] == 0) {
                leaf++;
                dfs(i, visited.get(), path.get(), path_i, cost + matrix[city][i]);
            }
        }
        if (leaf == 0) {
            cost += matrix[city][0];
            path[path_i] = 0;
            path_i++;

            if (cost < best_cost) {
                // printf("Found new best cost: %i\n", cost);
                best_cost = cost;
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    best_path[i] = path[i];
            }
        }
        free(visited);
        free(path);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, p;
// , source, dest;
//     int tag = 0;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(0, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (rank == 0) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m_row; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m_column; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    int temp = (rand() % zed) + 1;
                    matrix[i][j] = temp;
                    matrix[j][i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; i < p; i++)
            MPI_Send(&matrix[0][0], size * size, MPI_LONG, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("Matrix, %ix %i, Max Int : %i\n", m_row, m_column, zed);

        for (i = 0; i < m_row; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < m_column; j++)
                printf("%i\t", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            fflush(NULL);
        }
        printf("\n");
        int winner;
        int node_array[p - 1];
        int node_array_i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
            node_array[i] = i + 1;

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            int temp_best_cost, node;
            node = node_array[node_array_i];

            if (node_array_i < p - 2)
                node_array_i++;
            else
                node_array_i = 0;

            int* temp_best_path = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);

            MPI_Recv(&temp_best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            MPI_Recv(&temp_best_path[0], size + 1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            if (temp_best_cost < best_cost) {

                winner = node;
                best_cost = temp_best_cost;
                for (j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
                    best_path[j] = temp_best_path[j];
            }
            MPI_Send(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        printf("Best Path Found by node % i :\n", winner);
        printf("% i", best_path[0]);

        for (i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
            printf(" –> % i", best_path[i]);
        printf("\nBest Cost Found : % i\n", best_cost);

    } else {
        MPI_Recv(&(matrix[0][0]), m_row * m_column, MPI_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        int i;
        for (i = rank; i < size; i += (p - 1)) {

            int* visited = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);
            int* path    = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);

            int cost = matrix[0][i], path_i = 1;
            path[0] = 0;
            visited[0] = 1;
            dfs(i, visited.get(), path.get(), path_i, cost);

            MPI_Send(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&best_path[0], size + 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            free(visited);
            free(path);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

To my eyes it looks like `visited[]` from

```
int m_row = SIZE, m_column = SIZE, zed = 30, matrix[SIZE][SIZE], visited[SIZE], best_path[SIZE];
```

gets overwritten by

```
int* visited = calloc(sizeof(int), size + 1);
```

So, is that ok?

Also, in rank, at

```
MPI_Recv(&(matrix[0][0]), m_row * m_column, MPI_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

destination `matrix` looks like the same as origin `matrix` (does that make sense?), in rank 0, at:

```
MPI_Send(&matrix[0][0], size * size, MPI_LONG, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Since `matrix` is shared by all ranks, right?

```
int m_row = SIZE, m_column = SIZE, zed = 30, matrix[SIZE][SIZE], visited[SIZE], best_path[SIZE];
```

Also, I'll guess `best_path[]` (there on the begining) should be `best_path[SIZE+1]` instead of `best_path[SIZE]`. Because loop goes to `size+1`, right?

```
for (j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
    best_path[j] = temp_best_path[j];
```

Comment: I favor of keeping C++ tag, if u allow me, I'll say the question mention its beeing ported to C++. There is already C++ stuff there.

Comment: This `int node_array[p - 1];` is not valid C++, and `using std::make_unique;` is not valid C - make up your mind which language you are using

Comment: Edit your question and code to reflect which language you are asking about.

Comment: Am I not allowed to stay in a transition state (as mentioned in 1st line)? Considering stackoverflow allows both tags at same time.

Comment: SO would allow you to tag this code as Python and Pascal at the same time. The code you posted cannot be compiled with either a compliant C or C++ compiler/

Comment: Ok, question edited, now is C.

Comment: Why there is no error/warning for `int node_array[p - 1]`? I mean in the case of compiling it as C++.

Comment: gcc/g++ implement a few extensions.  This is one of them.  As regards `visited`, the declaration within `vfs` is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global declaration, until the end of the scope in which the local version is declared.  It is considered bad practice (because it requires the reader to remember which one they're getting when using the name) but is allowed.

Comment: I tried it on macOS, also no error/warning. So clang also accept it. I'm trying to believe its no valid C++ but the compilers don't complain here, or I'm not asking them correctly? Please could you name the extension which refers to this?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: As I expect you already know, GCC will happily compile code like this as C++, despite using variable-length automatic arrays.  If this makes GCC a "non-compliant C++ compiler" that's fine, but the fact is that it's probably the most widely used compiler in existence, so acting as if OP's code is unusable as written is a bit too much.

Comment: Why do you use `MPI_LONG` when matrix is an `int[][]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The first (global) `visited` variable is "shadowed" by the local one used with `calloc()`.  This isn't necessarily wrong, but it is poor coding style.

Yes, matrix is shared by all ranks (for some definition of shared).

As for the writing past the end of `best_path`, you're correct, that code is broken (it has undefined behavior).

Comment: Or should I think each node has his own `
matrix`?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Well, each process has its own `matrix` but the rank 0 process sends his version and overwrites the others.  By the way, that part of the code looks bad too--calling `MPI_Send()` in a loop over all ranks should be replaced with a single broadcast.  Overall I am not impressed with the quality of this code--hopefully you will work to improve it.